# C++/C execute code within a program under different user permission (program was originally invoked with sudo)

Tags: c++, linux, authentication, permissions

I want to call a program under sudo and have only one function within the program be run as though it was run as a different user.

e.g.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <unistd.h>

const std::string &REGULAR_USER = "non_root_user";

void print_whoami() {
    std::system("whoami");
}
void foo_run_as_sudo() {
    print_whoami();
    if (getuid())
        std::cout << "ERROR: this function should only be run under root privileges." << std::endl;
    // else: Execute some that requires elevated (sudo) privileges .
}
void foo_run_as_different_user() {
    // ??? Do something to switch user to REGULAR_USER ???
    print_whoami();
    if (!getuid())
        std::cout << "ERROR: this function cannot be run under sudo." << std::endl;
    // else: Call APIs that require non-sudo privileges / or require a different user.
}

int main() {
    if (getuid()) {
        std::cout << "ERROR: Must be run under sudo." << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }
    foo_run_as_sudo();
    foo_run_as_different_user();
    return 0;
}
```

Expected output:

```
$ sudo ./run_program
root
non_root_user
```

Is there / what is the mechanism to make this work?

Comment: Checkout [setuid](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages//man2/setuid.2.html).

Comment: setuid doesn't seem to be sufficient - beyond user ID, the API call internally uses some sort of credentials for that ID.

Comment: There is also [seteuid](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/seteuid.2.html).  I'm not sure what the difference is.